# Network error: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 149.154.167.220:443

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

I have this code block  in server.js file:

```
const Telegram = require('telegram-node-bot')

const tg = new Telegram.Telegram('***********token**************',{
    workers:1
});

const pingController = require('./controllers/ping')
    ,otherwiseController = require('./controllers/otherwise')

tg.router.when(new Telegram.TextCommand('/ping','pingCommand'), new pingController())
    .otherwise(new otherwiseController());
```

and this code block in ping.js file:

```
const Telegram = require('telegram-node-bot');
class pingController extends Telegram.TelegramBaseController{
    pingHandler($){
        $.sendMessage('pong');
    }

    get routes() {
        return{
            'pingCommand': 'pingHandler'
        };
    }
}

module.exports = pingController;
```

and finally this code block in otherwise file:

```
const Telegram = require('telegram-node-bot');
class otherwiseController extends Telegram.TelegramBaseController{
    handler($){
        $.sendMessage('Sorry!!!')
}
}

module.exports = otherwiseController;
```

when I run node server.js, I just got error like this:
[error]

> Network error: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 149.154.167.220:443
>       at Object._errnoException (util.js:1031:13)
>       at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1052:20)
>       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1195:14) request TelegramApiRequest {   _method: 'setWebhook',   _params: {
>   url: '' },   _multipart: undefined }

Also, the telegram is filtered in our country!!!, and I use the Siphon 3 proxy.

Answer (score 1):

its because you have't set your proxy for your terminal/cmd

for Linux:

```
export http_proxy='http://proxyserveraddress:3128'    
export https_proxy='https://proxyserveraddress:3128'
```

for Wndows:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxyserveraddress:3128    
set HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxyserveraddress:3128
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SOCKS5 proxy with the [socks5-https-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socks5-https-client) lib. Example:

```
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api')
const Agent = require('socks5-https-client/lib/Agent')

const bot = new TelegramBot(process.env.TELEGRAM_API_TOKEN, {
    polling: true,
    request: {
        agentClass: Agent,
        agentOptions: {
            socksHost: process.env.PROXY_SOCKS5_HOST,
            socksPort: parseInt(process.env.PROXY_SOCKS5_PORT),
            // If authorization is needed:
            // socksUsername: process.env.PROXY_SOCKS5_USERNAME,
            // socksPassword: process.env.PROXY_SOCKS5_PASSWORD
        }
    }
})
```

This solution to continue developing bot on your local PC (without proxy you can not start bots from Iran and Russia) and it works.

Answer (score 1):

If your country is limited Telegram, you should use a vpn or set a proxy as others said.